# What could cause console.log to not support method 'log'

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, console.log

All of a sudden, I am getting the following error when IE11 (not FF or Chrome) encounters `console.log(ayb);`.  There is too much other JavaScript on the page, and I am only asking for hypothetical causes or a strategy to troubleshoot.  When using `console.log(ayb);` without any other JavaScript on the page, it works as expected.

```
Object doesn't support property or method 'log'
```

Comment: Are you overwriting `console` somewhere on the page?

Comment: @Andy  It occurs once in two different scripts.

Comment: Sorry, thought you said `overwhelming`,  not `overwriting`.  No, I am not.